# What does "I/O Reads or Writes" and "I/O Read Bytes or Write Bytes" mean?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, task-manager, sysinternals

In Task Manager (and Sysinternals' Process Explorer) there are columns called "I/O Reads", "I/O Writes", "I/O Read Bytes" and "I/O Write Bytes". So what do these counters mean exactly? What else, besides disk and network activity, do they include?

In Process Explorer I see a number of processes which have zero "Disk Read Bytes" and "Network Receive Bytes", but a non-zero "I/O Read Bytes". And conversely, some processes have a "Disk Read Bytes" value larger than "I/O Read Bytes". How is this possible?

Comment: Why is the title "I/O Read **(Write)** Bytes" but in the question you simply say its "I/O Read Bytes"?

Comment: "I/O Reads" number is number of reads, "I/O Writes" is number of writes, "I/O Read Bytes" is total bytes read and "I/O Write Bytes is total bytes written. One read or write will transer many bytes at once.

Comment: @DavidPostill, have you read the entire question before commenting? I understand that "I/O Reads" number is number of reads, no need to get all captain obvious on me. Can you explain to me how is it possible that I have a process with e.g. 4 MiB "I/O Read Bytes" and zero "Disk Read Bytes"?

Comment: @Ramhound, I simply wanted to make the title shorter.

Comment: Be nice to David, we get lots of people with different skill levels, your question is confusing we are doing our best

Comment: @skr3am See my answer.

Answer (score 17):

#### How is it possible that I have a process with 4 MiB "I/O Read Bytes" and zero "Disk Read Bytes"?

I/O Read Bytes is more than just Disk Read Bytes:

- It includes File, Network and Device I/O
- It does **not** include Console I/O

> I/O Read Bytes - The number of bytes read in input/output operations generated by a process, including file, network, and device I/Os. I/O Read Bytes directed to CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not counted.

---

#### What does I/O data mean?

> **I/O Columns of Process Explorer**
>
> - I/O Delta - The change in I/O operations since the last measurement
> - I/O Delta Bytes - The change in I/O bytes since the last measurement.
> - I/O Other - The number of input/output operations generated by a process that are neither reads nor writes, including file, network,
>     and device I/Os. An example of this type of operation would be a
>     control function. I/O Others directed to CONSOLE (console input
>     object) handles are not counted.
> - I/O Other Bytes - The number of bytes transferred in input/output operations generated by a process that are neither reads nor writes,
>     including file, network, and device I/Os. An example of this type of
>     operation would be a control function. I/O Other Bytes directed to
>     CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not counted.
> - I/O Read Bytes - The number of bytes read in input/output operations generated by a process, including file, network, and device I/Os. I/O
>     Read Bytes directed to CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not
>     counted.
> - I/O Reads - The number of read input/output operations generated by a process, including file, network, and device I/Os. I/O Reads
>     directed to CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not counted.
> - I/O Write Bytes - The number of bytes written in input/output operations generated by a process, including file, network, and device
>     I/Os. I/O Write Bytes directed to CONSOLE (console input object)
>     handles are not counted.
> - I/O Writes - The number of write input/output operations generated by a process, including file, network, and device I/Os. I/O Writes
>     directed to CONSOLE (console input object) handles are not counted.

Source [Trying to understand Process Explorer's I/O data](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/trying-to-understand-i-o-nomenclature.286453/)