# Windows 10 running slow

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 running slow sometimes or hang. Task managers shows disk 100% usage.

My laptop configuration;

1) Operating System

```
Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit
```

2) CPU

```
Intel Core i7 5500U @ 2.40GHz   
Broadwell-U 14nm Technology
```

3) RAM

```
16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz (11-11-11-28)
```

4) Motherboard

```
Dell Inc.
```

5) Graphics

```
Generic PnP Monitor (1600x900@60Hz)
Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Dell)
4095MB NVIDIA GeForce 920M (Dell)   
ForceWare version: 353.62
SLI Disabled
```

6) Storage

```
1863GB Seagate ST2000LM003 HN-M201RAD (SATA)
```

7) Optical Drives

```
PLDS DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH
```

8) Audio

```
Realtek High Definition Audio
```

Comment: From when you are getting this issue. After installing any software or antivirus?

Comment: Using 2-3 software at a time.

Comment: How old is your machine / HDD?

Comment: Such a question is very general and unanswerable. You must try to refine the problem better. Use Sysinternals ProcessExplorer to see, what process is using the disk.

Comment: @Darius Brought laptop 8 months ago. Don't know manufacture date of HDD.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Can you help me that?

Comment: Check if write caching is enabled in your HDD.  Right-click logo, choose device manager, select "disk drives", double click your drive, select "Policies" tab, check the option to "Enable write caching on the device".

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and click to start. Now capture 1 minute of the DiskIO. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll try to analyze it

Comment: have you captured the trace?

Answer (score 0):

Run a tool named [Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe).

After you have started Process Explorer, click on the View menubar item and then Select Columns.

[image]

Click on the Process I/O tab and check:

- Read Bytes
- Write Bytes
- History

Hit OK.

You will see a separate chart of I/O activity for each process under `I/O History` column and amount of data read and written. It is not only disk activity, [see here](https://superuser.com/a/994079/285900), but most of it should be disk or network activity, so you can try to disconnect from network to see only disk activity.

There you should determine, which process is eating your disk performance. Usually that process would also consume some significant processor time.

---

Some services are reported that can cause 100% disk usage. You can try to stop them one by one using following commands and see if it helps:

```
net.exe stop WSearch
net.exe stop Superfetch
net.exe stop Bits
```

You should also scan your PC with [MBAM Antimalware](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).