# How is it possible for a process to read 300+ I/O TB?

Tags: networking, io, process-explorer

[image]

Take a look at how much I/O this process done! `KillerAnalyticsService` is, apparently, program made by the manufacturer of network card installed in PC. Can somebody explain how so much bytes was read?

Using [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/993966/what-does-i-o-reads-or-writes-and-i-o-read-bytes-or-write-bytes-mean) I made hypothesis that, because its not Disk I/O and it's not Network I/O (nowhere near the values shown in general I/O tab) the only thing left is Device I/O. So this means, that `KillerAnalyticsService` communicates with the network card using this colossal amount of data?

Comment: All your processes have very high values. How long have they been running? You can see this in the process properties window.

Comment: Modern versions of Windows only close user programs and hibernate the core of the OS. If you have only been using the "shutdown" command and have not rebooted recently then it is possible that this program has been running "continuously" for weeks as a system service which would not be closed when you shutdown. It is possible that the data shown at 300TB is several weeks or months of downloads, uploads, and disk usage while the other programs are only from the current time you logged in. Have you disabled Windows update?

Answer (score 1):

This program is part of [Intel Killer Intelligence Center](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/wireless/killer/intelligence-center.html), which is probably part of your package with wifi network drivers. As you can see it collect also information about other wireless networks so for me such amount of transferred bytes (>300TB) looks feasible. But if you do not use this control center you can remove it and the program will disappear from the list of processes. Also this is a service so you can stop it and test if such act harm your work.